# Kubernetes : Inter-cluster networking

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to set up inter-cluster communication between two k8s clusters (preferably using google's managed service, gke).

Usecase(simplified):- Cluster A has client apps and cluster B has server apps.  Communication has to be possible both ways. I tried with creating two new vnets say A and B and peering vnetA and vnetB . Also, vnetA is given in --network argumnet for cluster A(alongwith its subnet) and similarly for cluster B - vnet B. I also exposed my server app in cluster B using a gcp internal load-balancer.

Now, from a new standalone VM in vnet A, I am able to access server app in cluster B(using its internal LB-IP) but am not able to access same from a client app running as container in cluster A.

I have doubts about egress from my cluster. Please help/guide.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to add a comment.

Are you using IP Aliases for kubernetes? From [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering#gke_name_short_with_vpc_network_peering), VPC Network Peering with Kubernetes Engine is supported when used with IP Aliases.

Comment: I have not used IP aliases as of now since it is a beta feature. Will go with it if it is mandatorily needed.